# Fullcalendar keeps changing CSS rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

my problem here is about styling some holiday events.

I had fetch the eventSource with regular events and holiday events, marked like: `event.holiday = true`

What I'm trying to do is show regular events and hiding those holiday events with a css rule `display : none`, and changing the color of the day number. I add a `holiday` class for being able to access from jQuery before.

This is the piece of code that changes the color of the day number:

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view){
            $('.fc-day-number').each(function () {
                var currentDate = (new 
                Date(event.start)).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                var day = $(this).parent().attr('data-date');
                if (currentDate == day && event.holiday) {
                    $(this).addClass('holiday');
                }
            });
}
```

And it works, it changes the color, but if I click to change month, it'll disappear.

Am I missing something? Is there any easier way to achieve this?

Comment: would you be better using the "background events" to represent your holidays? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/ . It sounds pretty similar to what you're trying to achieve - don't show an actual event box, just change the colour in the background.

Comment: While I was testing your idea, I realized that it banishes too.

So I put `stick:true` on the Holiday eventSource, and it keeps! Thank you so much!

Comment: Ah ok, didn't realise you were adding the events on the client side - you talked about an eventsource, so assumed it was coming from the server. But yeah any event you add client side using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/ would need the `stick` parameter setting true. Bit confused how you can set that on a whole event source, though?

Comment: I made it via JSON, grab the events from the controller and pass them via JSON to the js file.

Comment: Ok so not by specifying an event URL directly, like this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ or this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventSources/? That would be the normal way that fullCalendar expects you to do it. Then it will automatically make a call out to fetch the events for new time periods when the user changes the view/dates etc. Or if you need more flexibility you can use the events-as-a-function callback: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ . If you do it like this there should be no need for "stick" properties.

Comment: I just needed a only-read calendar, so I fetched the events via json feed.

It's rough solution, but it works as expected.

Comment: doesn't matter if it's read-only or not, the links I've given there are not for updating events or sending data to the server, they're for dynamically fetching a subset of events based on the dates being displayed currently on the calendar. If you have a large set of events in your database (or will have in future, once you've been using the application for some time) this will normally be more efficient than downloading everything up front, especially if users are relatively unlikely to browse (a long way) back in time to view old events.

Comment: You scared me a little bit, but after a few checks, I think the events are being passed like the first link. 

I have a JSON method in my home controller, and then, I fill the eventSource with that method, but after all of that, in the .js file of the calendar, I gather them with `$http.get`, read every value I need from it with Angular, and pushed into eventSources, it'll be correct this way?

Comment: not really - as per the first link I gave, you'd give fullCalendar the URL of your controller directly, not via another JS method. It's hard to be sure just from a description though. If you want to ask another question about it, and post the code directly on here I can take a look and see if it's the expected way to do it, or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was the option `stick:true`, that wasn't enabled for the Holiday Events.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think that this part of code

```
if (currentDate == day && event.holiday) {
    $(this).addClass('holiday');
 }
```

changes this color and especialy a addClass('holiday').
you can try to style this class in your css file

Comment: Sorry if I not mentioned it, but it's already in the .css file, and like I said, it prints out red!

The problem is if I change month, and go back again to the day with the number in red, it goes back to black (original color).

Comment: can you provide some link ?

Comment: I'm testing it locally, let me try uploading to fiddle.

Comment: This is not accurate, but here you go, I can see how it's holiday class added, but it dissapear after the month change 

https://i.imgur.com/tPbzBIK.gif

Comment: I can provide full js script if you want to.

Comment: so it looks like, changing month is reloading your your function to display month and it renders it from begining so you may want to think about some stroage for variables responsible for changing color